# Dusk cannot dismiss dialog because of UnexpectedAlertOpenException

Tags: phpunit, laravel-5.7, laravel-dusk

I am using Laravel Dusk to write browser tests for a Laravel 5.7 application. In the test I am navigating to the page and clicking a button which triggers a confirm dialog. I am trying to test that dismissing the dialog does not change the page url.

I have tried adding `$this-expectException(UnexpectedAlertOpenException::class)` before running the test to try to make the code understand a dialog should be shown

```
    {
        $this->expectException(UnexpectedAlertOpenException::class);

        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
            $browser->loginToWave()
                ->goToSystemsEdit();

            $browser->waitFor('@delete-systems-button')
                ->click('@delete-systems-button')
                ->assertDialogOpened('This will delete the system. Please seek advice before doing this. Continue?')
                ->dismissDialog()
                ->assertPathBeginsWith('systems/edit');
        });
    }
```

I expect the test to dismiss the dialog and check the path assertion.

What is actually happening is that an `UnexpectedAlertOpenException` is thrown:

```
1) Tests\Browser\Systems\DeleteSystemTest::testSystemNotDeletedIfConfirmIsDismissed
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnexpectedAlertOpenException: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : This will delete the system. Please seek advice before doing this. Continue?}
  (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615279 (12b89733300bd268cff3b78fc76cb8f3a7cc44e5),platform=Linux 4.9.125-linuxkit x86_64)

/var/www/html/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Exception/WebDriverException.php:140
/var/www/html/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/HttpCommandExecutor.php:326
/var/www/html/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php:547
/var/www/html/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php:345
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Browser.php:261
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:139
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php:418
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:140
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:69
/var/www/html/tests/DuskTestCase.php:68
```

Comment: What's the whole stacktrace?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I've added it above

Comment: Which line in your test causes the error?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I don't know, the stack trace doesn't give me that information. I'm assuming it's the line where I click the button

Comment: Can you create a minimal application to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Dusk does not seem ready for primetime, I am stuck here also